# Can I cast a tuple struct enum variant into a regular tuple instead of destructuring and recreating the tuple?

Tags: struct, enums, rust, tuples

I have a tuple struct enum variant that looks like this:

```rust
enum Message {
    ChangeColor(u8, u8, u8),
    // ...
}
```

Later, I have a `match` construct to detect if a variable is of the `ChangeColor` subtype.

```rust
match message {
    Message::ChangeColor(r, g, b) => self.change_color((r, g, b)),
    // ...
}
```

The signature of `change_color` is `change_color(&mut self, color: (u8, u8, u8))`.  Is there any way to pass the value of `message` directly to `self.change_color` by casting it to the equivalent tuple type, or am I required to deconstruct `message` and then construct a new tuple to pass to `change_color`?

It's not that I'm concerned with performance.  I've read that the compiler knows how to pass `message` directly instead of literally copying the values to a new tuple first.  I'm more concerned with ergonomics.  Do I really have to repeat myself there and possibly mistype something and introduce an error or a bug?

Comment: what's wrong with helper function ? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9f68241fc9bdf2c49f1001bd63f90e2e and I don't think your current code bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two ways to answer this.

1. For the `enum`-definition as written, you do need to do the explicit destructuring and subseuquent tuple construction. One simple reason for this: The language does not guarantee that the layout of the fields in `Message::ChangeColor` matches the layout of `(u8, u8, u8)`. So from that point of view, it makes some sense that you cannot convert the `Message::ChangeColor` payload into its own tuple.
2. If you really do not want to repeat the destructuring and restructuring, and if you are willing to modify your `enum`-definition *slightly*, then I recommend you define your `enum` like this:

```
enum Message {
   ChangeColor((u8, u8, u8)), // note the extra set of parentheses.
   // ...
}
```

With this in place, you can now match the *tuple* that the enum holds, and pass *that* to `self.change_color`. [Demo playground code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e4f8898dff7cae2ad0a606d3f26dbef6)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass extra parenthesis for `enum`. see [demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=53bbb526c23233bcb0fc31e2bcd08680)

```
enum Message {
    ChangeColor (u8, u8, u8),
}
match message {
     Message::ChangeColor(r, g, b) => self.change_color((r, g, b)),
     ...
}

Interp.recv(Message::ChangeColor(1,2,3));
```